# javascript cannnot detect same element in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below:

```js
var classCode = "";
var colorUsed = [];
var classes = [];
var color = ["yellow", "lightblue", "lightgreen", "pink", "orange", "cyan", "lightgrey", "plum", "wheat", "khaki"];

function colorClass(row) {
  classCode = $(row).html();
  var index = -1;

  if (colorUsed.length != 0) {
    index = classes.indexOf(classCode);
  } else {
    index = -1;
  }

  while (index == -1) {
    colorNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));

    if (!(color[colorNum] in colorUsed)) {
      colorUsed.push(color[colorNum]);
      classes.push(classCode);
      index = 1;
    } else {
      alert("same color!");
      index = -1;
    }
  }

  if (index != -1) {
    colorNum = classes.indexOf(classCode);;
  }

  $(row).css("background-color", colorUsed[colorNum]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
 <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
    <th>Savings for holiday!</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr><td colspan="3" onclick="colorClass(this);">ClassA</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="3" onclick="colorClass(this);">ClassC</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="3" onclick="colorClass(this);">ClassD</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="3" onclick="colorClass(this);">ClassE</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="3" onclick="colorClass(this);">ClassF</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="3" onclick="colorClass(this);">ClassG</td></tr>
  <tr><td colspan="3" onclick="colorClass(this);">ClassH</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I use "in" function to avoid same color to apply, but it is not working, I know there is another way to use which to loop the element one-by-one and compare it, but I don't like to use that.

Or any other way to detect it? Since there is no hashset in javascript, is it possible to implement in Jquery?

Comment: jQuery === JavaScript.

Comment: Look at `Array.indexOf()` - that will remove the need for your first check and the later `in`

Comment: @Utkanos Javascript !== jQuery, so asking if there are methods in jQuery to help is a valid question.

Comment: You need `indexOf()`, not `in`. Your code is most likely throwing at least one syntax error as `in` is not intended to be used as you are

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing

```
if (!(color[colorNum] in colorUsed)) {
```

as

```
if (colorUsed.indexOf(color[colorNum]) == -1) {
```

Hope it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object for `colorUsed`.

```
var colorUsed = {};

// assign
colorUsed[color[colorNum]] = true;

// test, as you already had
if (!(color[colorNum] in colorUsed)) {

// test, shorter
if (!colorUsed[color[colorNum]]) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm writting this answer to add some explanation for the answers already given:

In javascript, an array is an Object which maps integer keys (starting from 0) to their values.

Using the `in` operator on an array is not what you are looking for. This will check a property exists on the array (because – yet again – it's an object). It will be `true` for Array properties like `length`, for inherited properties like `toString` and for the keys of the array like `0` in case of an array with a size bigger than 1.
It will not evaluate as `true` with the values of the array, except if the array contains weird values like "length".

If you want to look for a value, you can as others have suggested either use `colorUsed.indexOf` or use another structure like a hash in the form of a javascript object .